# Gradient descent does not return incorrect prediction for linear function

Tags: algorithm, matlab, machine-learning

I've implemented following Batch Gradient descednt algorithm, based on various sources I was able to find around web and in lecture notes.

This implementation isn't ideal in terms of stopping criteria, but for my sample it should work.

Inputs:

```
x = [1,1;1,2;1,3;1,4;1,5];
y = [1;2;3;4;5];
theta = [0;0];
```

Code:

```
tempTheta = [0;0];

for c = 1:10000,
    for j = 1:2,
        sum = 0;
        for i = 1:5,
            sum = sum + ((dot(theta', x(i, :)) - y(j)) * x(i,j)); 
        end
        sum = (sum / 5) * 0.01;

        tempTheta(j) = theta(j) - sum;
    end
    theta = tempTheta;
end
```

The expected result is `theta = [0;1]`, but my implementation always returns  `theta = [-3.5, 1.5]`.

I've tried various combinations of alpha and starting point, but without luck. Where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
sum = sum + ((dot(theta', x(i, :)) - y(j)) * x(i,j));
```

you are using a wrong index of `y`, it should be `y(i)`, as `j` is a dimension iterator, not  the sample iterator.

After the change

```
theta =

  -1.5168e-07
   1.0000e+00
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.